# How to use variable for data in Charts.js Pie Chart?

Tags: jquery, chart.js

I am trying to generate a pie chart with values from textboxes. I am using Chart.js. This is the code with hard-coded values and it works fine:

```
<script>
        var sharePiePolorDoughnutData = [
        {
            value: 50,
            color: "#455C73",
            highlight: "#34495E",
            label: "Si Day"
    },
        {
            value: 50,
            color: "#9B59B6",
            highlight: "#B370CF",
            label: "Si Night"
    },
        {
            value: 150,
            color: "#BDC3C7",
            highlight: "#CFD4D8",
            label: "Mi Day"
    }

];

    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.myPie = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas_doughnut").getContext("2d")).Pie(sharePiePolorDoughnutData, {
            responsive: true,
            tooltipFillColor: "rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.55)"
        });
    });
```

I have tried this but it still does not work:

```
<script>
    var charttotalsedaypic = document.getElementById("tbtotalsedaypic").value;
    var sharePiePolorDoughnutData = [
        {
            value: [charttotalsedaypic],
            color: "#455C73",
            highlight: "#34495E",
            label: "Si Day"
    },
        {
            value: 50,
            color: "#9B59B6",
            highlight: "#B370CF",
            label: "Si Night"
    },
        {
            value: 150,
            color: "#BDC3C7",
            highlight: "#CFD4D8",
            label: "Mi Day"
    }
];

    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.myPie = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas_doughnut").getContext("2d")).Pie(sharePiePolorDoughnutData, {
            responsive: true,
            tooltipFillColor: "rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.55)"
        });
    });
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution, i'm posting it here in case anyone else runs into the same problem in the future.

It turns out I just needed to use parseFloat. so the part that was changed was:

```
var sharePiePolorDoughnutData = [
                                       {
                                          value: [charttotalsedaypic],
                                          color: "#455C73",
                                          highlight: "#34495E",
                                          label: "Si Day"
                                       },
```

and i parsed the variable and the final code is:

```
var sharePiePolorDoughnutData = [
{
  value: parseFloat(charttotalsedaypic),
  color: "#455C73",
  highlight: "#34495E",
  label: "Si Day"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just move the two variable declaration in onDeviceReady function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Creating chart</title>
   <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
   <script type = "text/javascript" src="Chart.js"> </script>
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
           var charttotalsedaypic = document.getElementById("tbtotalsedaypic").value;

           var sharePiePolorDoughnutData = [
                                           {
                                              value: [charttotalsedaypic],
                                              color: "#455C73",
                                              highlight: "#34495E",
                                              label: "Si Day"
                                           },
                                           {
                                             value: 50,
                                             color: "#9B59B6",
                                             highlight: "#B370CF",
                                             label: "Si Night"
                                           },
                                           {
                                             value: 150,
                                             color: "#BDC3C7",
                                             highlight: "#CFD4D8",
                                             label: "Mi Day"
                                           }
                                         ];
  window.myPie = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas_doughnut").getContext("2d")).Pie(sharePiePolorDoughnutData, {
      responsive: true,
      tooltipFillColor: "rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.55)"
  });
  });

  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <input type="text" value="11" id="tbtotalsedaypic"/>
     <canvas id="canvas_doughnut" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
   </body>
    </html>
```

As the value is not set, so the value return gives null and that's why it is not rendered using the chart.

Comment: HI Punit, thanks for your response. I tried that and the chart does not render, it "goes crazy" and shows the second value (50) and does not show the value of [charttotalsedaypic]

Comment: Thanks Punit. It still doesn't work. I read the documentation and it says that "value" has to be a number. So when i tried var charttotalsedaypic = 1; it works. I think the issue is it is not reading the value of the variable as a number.

Comment: Have you tried this sample posted by me. Can you post your html input field.

Comment: Yes I tried that. My html input box looks like this:<input type="text" id="tbtotalsedaypic"> The value of the input box is populated by a javascript file using this: divtotalsedaypic.value = totalsedaypic.toFixed(1)

Comment: Might be your are not setting numeric value. You can render chart on button click, where you can check whether value entered in input is numeric or not and then render the chart.